# Beam number program seems impossible to write using multiple void methods

Tags: java, global-variables, void

A Beam number is a number in which the sum of the squares of the digits of the number is larger than the number itself.

For example: In the no. 25, sum of the square of digits = 2^2 + 5^2 = 4 + 25 = 29 (greater than the number accepted)

Hence 25 is a Beam number.

I am a student and am trying to write a program for a practical assignment, but I can't seem to find any solutions. Here is a picture of the assignment: [Assignment pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNZ7J.png)

Here is my attempt:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Beam3meth
{
    static int sum,m;
    public static void getNum()
    {
        System.out.println("\f");//clearing the screen
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number");
        m = sc.nextInt(); 
        int flag = m;
    }
    public static void squareSum()
    {
        sum  = 0;
        while (m > 0)
        {
            sum = sum + (m%10)*(m%10);
            m = m/10;
        }
    }
    public static void isBeam()
    {
        if (sum > flag)
        {
            System.out.println("It is a Beam number");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("It is not a Beam number");
        }
    }
    public static void main()
    {
        Beam3meth obj = new Beam3meth();
        obj.getNum();
        obj.squareSum();
        obj.isBeam();
        
    }
    
}
```

The problem is that there can only be 2 global variables (which have to be used in 2 or more methods), as specified in the assignment details. But then there is also flag variable (which is used to copy m's value before it gets reduced to 0), which has to be used in 2 methods. All 3 methods have to be void as well, so you can't do any Call By Reference / return a value. What changes should I make so as to accommodate all restrictions?

Comment: There are no restrictions on local variables so you can use one when calculating the squared sum, so you can leave m unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Your assignment does not ask for static variables. It only says that the class Beam should have two instance variables i.e. m & sum. You can always use local variables within the functions and store values in those.

The following steps should solve the problem:

1. You do not have to make m & sum static. Same goes for all the functions. Static functions can be called without making an object of the class. This would not be the case here.
2. You don't need the int flag = m; line either. Delete that.
3. Instead of modifying m, create a local variable within the function initially initialized to the value of m and then modify that variable instead. It's completely okay to do that. You can create as many local variables as you want and still meet the conditions for this assignment.
4. Create a separate class called main for the main function. Create an instance of the beam class there and call the functions.

Here's the code for how I solved this problem:

P.S. Your logic for the squareSum function is also correct. Just don't modify m. Create a local variable instead (I created quot in my code).

```
import java.util.*;

class Beam
{
    int m;
    int sum;
    
    public Beam()
    {
        m = 0;
        sum = 0;
    }
    
    void getNum()
    {
        System.out.print("Enter a number  ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        this.m = sc.nextInt();
    }
    
    void squareSum()
    {
        int mod, quot = m, div = 10;
        
        while(quot >= div/10 )
        {
            mod = quot%div;
            sum = sum + mod*mod;
            quot = quot/div;
        }
    }
    
    void isBeam()
    {
        if(sum>m)
        {
            System.out.println("The integer " + m + " is a beam number");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("The integer " + m + " is not a beam number");
        }
    }
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Beam b = new Beam();
        b.getNum();
        b.squareSum();
        b.isBeam();
        
    }
}
```